# Django request.POST empty

Tags: python, forms, post, request, submit

I'm using python/django 2.1.2. Editor is Visual Studio 2015.

I'm getting an empty request.POST after submitting a form.

My simplified form:

```
{% extends "compilados/_layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>New</h2>
<br/>

    <form action="{% url 'compilado:crear' %}" method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre:</td><td><input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre"/></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Crear" />

    </form>


{% endblock content%}
```

My simplified url file:

```
from app import c_views
import django.contrib.auth.views

app_name = 'compilado'

urlpatterns = [
    path ( '/crear', c_views.Crear, name = 'crear' ),
]
```

My simplified views file:

```
import django.contrib.auth.views
import os

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest, Http404
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

def Crear ( request ):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Datos = NuevoCompiladoForm ( request.POST )
        NuevoCompilado = Compilado ()
        Resultado = NuevoCompilado.Crear ( Datos )
        if Resultado == 'OK':
            return Indice ( request )
        else:
            return render ( request, 'compilados/Resultado.html', {'proceso':'Creacion de cabecera de nuevo compilado y lectura de sus elementos','resultado':Resultado} )
```

The problem: up until 2 days ago this was working perfectly OK. If I set a breakpoint on "if request.method == 'POST':" and I inspect "request" I used to get a list of values in POST. However now POST is empty. I get this:

[(see image of inspect with empty POST)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHQEk.png)

We sniffed the traffic and we got this:

```
POST http://localhost:58307/compilados/crear HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58307
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:58307/compilados/nuevo
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 66
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=RnPKStaBKIx6oYjyArlctDZSZMQFChF1gqwVRs1KZAZA2AtiYOpzmAzaH0CGezXG
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

nombre=10&ejercicio=20&raiz=30&comentario=40&plantillas=50&salida=
```

Last line shows the info I typed on the form, however I still get an empty POST. I've read previuos posts about reading body instead of POST when using JSON, but this is not the case.

No changes have been made to the source code. I extracted one of the many copies that I regularly make (about 2 weeks old) and I get the same empty POST, although 2 weeks ago it was working. It must be a configuration issue, but since I'm a noob I'm lost.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try sending a request with Postman?

Comment: Tried it with Insomnia, but got the same result. Just to try things out I changed **`"action = 'POST'"`** to **`"action = 'GET'"`** in my form template, and it worked, my request.GET has all the data correctly loaded. However, this is not good practice,  I don't want to close the case yet, I need to know how I screwed up my request.POST.

Comment: Thats strange. I reproduced your setup from what you posted and I don't get empty POST dictionary.

Comment: I advise you to start using class based views. The code is more readable that way.

Comment: Could this be a browser issue or a Windows issue? I've tried with Firefox, Edge and Chrome, but I still get an empty POST.

Comment: What do you get in body if you check the post request in chrome developer tools => network?

Comment: `Request header (567 B) 
Accept 
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Length 
287
Content-Type 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie 
csrftoken=RnPKStaBKIx6oYjyArlc…VRs1KZAZA2AtiYOpzmAzaH0CGezXG
Host 
localhost:61847
Referer 
http://localhost:61847/compilados/nuevo
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests 
1
User-Agent 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0`

Comment: `Response header (162 B) 
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=utf-8
Date 
Tue, 13 Nov 2018 13:19:36 GMT
Server 
WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.4
Transfer-Encoding 
chunked`

Comment: `Form data 
comentario Test+on+request.POST
csrfmiddlewaretoken 6b0wUv8XxOUjAHz6kSyYVbL4ZhnAcZflljX5CiMsZOQ8InPgjEl40rVya0Twrlap
ejercicio 2018
nombre Test+01
plantillas C:\PruebaConversion\Plantillas
raiz C:\PruebaConversion\Ejemplos\Reducido06
salida C:\PruebaConversion\Salida`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format the three previous comments. However, the last one shows that the form data gets loaded in the request, but I still get no content on request.POST. I can't stop thinking that it has to be a configuration issue, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: I think it is configuration issue, because in the last comment you can see the form data. csrfmiddlewaretoken 6b0wUv8XxOUjAHz6kSyYVbL4ZhnAcZflljX5CiMsZOQ8InPgjEl40rVya0Twrlap ejercicio 2018 nombre Test+01. Can you post the settings file? And hide the sensitive data such as SECRET_KEY

Comment: It was a configuration issue indeed, but a strange one (I guess!!). Thanks so much for your help. I closed the post, but please read the follow-up that I've written.