# request.POST empty after upgrading from Django 1.11 to Django 2.1

Tags: python, django, post, url-pattern

This post is a follow-up of this previous question:

[Django request.POST empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227767/django-request-post-empty)

I had a project up and running with Python 3.5.4 and Django **1.11.13**, on Visual Studio 2015. I later updated to Django **2.1.2** because I wanted to import the "path" module, so that I can use this:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path ( '',                                c_views.Indice,              name = 'indice' ),
    path ( '<int:CompiladoID>',               c_views.Detalle,             name = 'detalle'),
    path ( 'elementos/<int:CompiladoID>',     c_views.Elementos,           name = 'elementos'),
    path ( 'datoselementos/<int:ElementoID>', c_views.DatosElemento,       name = 'datoselemento'),
```

...instead of this:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url ( r'^$',                                    c_views.Indice,         name = 'indice'),
    url ( r'^(?P<CompiladoID>\d+)/$',               c_views.Detalle,        name = 'detalle' ),
    url ( r'^(?P<CompiladoID>\d+)/elementos$',      c_views.Elementos,      name = 'elementos' ),
    url ( r'^(?P<CompiladoID>\d+)/generar$',        c_views.Generar,        name = 'generar' ),
```

which I find easier to declare and read. After this change I started to experience problems with request.POST. I got a "request" response, but POST was empty, as shown here:

[image: see inspection window with empty request.POST]

Actually, I was not initially aware of this. It's taken me 3 days, and a compare with a backup copy that I've recovered, to realize that Django version was different. That said, I'm puzzled about the fact that a **newer** version of Django should not be able to do something that older versions did, unless something has changed that I don't know of. I've only been working with Python/Django for a couple of months, can anyone tell me if there is a reason to this? Can I not use `path` instead of `url` for my `urlpatterns` using Django 2.1.2?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT** (november 14th)

This is my `settings.py` (I basically added `'app'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`):

```
"""
Django settings for MemoProject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import posixpath

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '---'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app',
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MemoProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MemoProject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this has anything to do with path vs url. And of course Django 2.1 definitely can receive POST parameters, it wouldn't be much use as a web framework if it couldn't. Therefore the problem is definitely somewhere else. One possible culprit is middleware; can you post your middleware settings?

Comment: what's the content of `request.data`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You're right, I don't think it has anything to do with `url` vs `path`. It's just that `path` didn't work with Django 1.11, so I updated to Django 2.1 in order to use it. But, apparently, _as a side effect_, `request.POST` started to show up empty. But I agree with you, the problem must be somewhere else, this doesn't seem right. I'm new to this, so I'm probably screwing up some configuration option. I'll edit the original post to add my `settings.py`, please look it up there. As for my `request.data`, I have no such element (please see the image above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` was deprecated in Django 1.10 and [removed in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-0). You should be using [`MIDDLEWARE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/) instead.

You should remove `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` because it [hasn't been required since Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-10).

Django 1.11 gives a deprecation warning that you should switch from `MIDDLEWARE`, but you must have missed this. Before upgrading Django, it's good practice to read the release notes, and fix any deprecation warnings. See the [upgrade guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/upgrade-version/) for more info.